# Builtin function failing for input in python

Tags: python, function, tuples, output

I am trying to return a tuples list composed by each keyword and count of occurences for each keyword and its synonyms for each document.

I have no problem when the input is just one string ("happy" for example), however when I try for more inputs ("happy" and "sad" for example) the code just prints output for the last one ("sad")

Here's my code:

```
class Entry :
    def __init__(self, input_word, input_synonyms) :
        self.word = input_word
        self.synonyms = input_synonyms

e1 = Entry("sad", ["unhappy", "upset"])
e2 = Entry("happy", ["cheerful", "joyful"])
Thesaurus = [e1, e2]
doc1 = ["the", "man", "is", "sad", "very", "sad", "and", "unhappy", "and", "upset"]
doc2 = ["the", "boy", "is", "happy", "cheerful", "and", "joyful"]
Corpus = [doc1, doc2]

def search(keyword) :
    all_words = [keyword]
    for entry in Thesaurus:
        if entry.word == keyword:
            for word in entry.synonyms:
                all_words.append(word)
    store = []
    for search_word in all_words:
        count = 0
        for document in Corpus:
            for word in document:
                if search_word == word:
                    count = count + 1
        store.append([search_word, count])
    return store

input_ = "happy" and "sad"
output = search(input_)
print(output)
```

Console output:

```
[['sad', 2], ['unhappy', 1], ['upset', 1]]
```

Expected output:

```
[['happy', 1], ['cheerful', 1], ['joyful', 1], ['sad', 2], ['unhappy', 1], ['upset', 1]]
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: `"happy" and "sad"` evaluates to `"sad"`.  First the truth value of `"happy"` is checked.  Since it's considered true, then `"sad"` is evaluated and becomes the value of the expression.  Were you trying to construct a `tuple`?  The syntax for a `tuple` would be `("happy", "sad")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking in consideration @Tom Karzes comment,

The next code worked fine:

```
class Entry :
    def __init__(self, input_word, input_synonyms) :
        self.word = input_word
        self.synonyms = input_synonyms

e1 = Entry("sad", ["unhappy", "upset"])
e2 = Entry("happy", ["cheerful", "joyful"])
Thesaurus = [e1, e2]
doc1 = ["the", "man", "is", "sad", "very", "sad", "and", "unhappy", "and", "upset"]
doc2 = ["the", "boy", "is", "happy", "cheerful", "and", "joyful"]
Corpus = [doc1, doc2]

def search(keyword) :
    all_words = ["happy", "cheerful", "joyful", "sad", "unhappy", "upset"]
    for entry in Thesaurus:
        if entry.word == keyword:
            for word in entry.synonyms:
                all_words.append(word)
    store = []
    for search_word in all_words:
        count = 0
        for document in Corpus:
            for word in document:
                if search_word == word:
                    count = count + 1
        store.append([search_word, count])
    return store

input_ = ("happy", "cheerful", "joyful", "sad", "unhappy", "upset")
output = search(input_)
print(output)
```

Console output:

```
[['happy', 1], ['cheerful', 1], ['joyful', 1], ['sad', 2], ['unhappy', 1], ['upset', 1]]
```